# How to write this Google Spreadsheet percentage calculation function?

Tags: google-sheets

I track my diet (macros) in Google Spreadsheets.

For 1 day my protein is `114.63` carbs `194.75` and fat `69.15`, the `70.54` is sugar which I'm not sure I should include.

The total of all 3 is `378.53`

Using [math.com's percentage calculator](http://www.math.com/students/calculators/source/3percent.htm) I can see that **69** is `18.253`% of **378**, however I'm not sure how to write the formula in Google Spreadsheets.

This is my current formula:

`=SUM(G30/D30/100)`

I take the sum `(G30 = 378)` divide it by `(D30 = 69)` fat, and divide that by 100 and I get `5.47`% :(

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have it backwards.

You need to divide your fat by protein, then multiply by 100 to get the percentage value.

```
=D30/G30*100
```

69 / 378 = 0.18253968254

If you use the percentage format on the cell, you can skip multiplying by 100.

You don't need the `sum()` function at all here. That's for summing an array of cells.