# Google Spreadsheet Percentage of Price in Column

Tags: google-sheets

After searching through several sites this seemed to be the best area for Google Spreadsheet questions and after browsing through the tag [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) and searching for [price](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheets%5D%20price) I didn't see this asked before.  Closest question found was [How to write this Google Spreadsheet percentage calculation function?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80981/how-to-write-this-google-spreadsheet-percentage-calculation-function). So here goes, I have a four column spreadsheet that I would like to narrow down to three columns.  The current spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

My end goal is to input `Price` and `Percent Off` and then calculate the `End Price` without having a hidden column, in this case `Percent Price`.  Currently my process is:

- Price is input in column D
- Percent off is input in Column C
- Column B calculates the percentage with `=round(D2*C2,2)`
- Column A takes the percent price and subtracts from Price `=(D2-B2)`

So my question is, how can I get End Price with two columns (Percent Off & Price)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following in your End Price column:

```
=FullPrice-ROUND(FullPrice*PercentDiscount,2)
```

FullPrice = Column with the full price.

PercentOff = Column with the percentage discount you want to apply.

Comment: @pnuts that is true, I did edit that area but it gets me closer to the calculation I wanted.